Why attached agents are not allowed to use breakpoints?
Dynamically attached agent can not add can_generate_breakpoint_events capability (answer is JVMTI_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE). The direct reason is in JVM source code:
jvmtiCapabilities JvmtiManageCapabilities::init_onload_solo_capabilities() {
  jvmtiCapabilities jc;

  memset(&jc, 0, sizeof(jc));
  jc.can_generate_field_modification_events = 1;
  jc.can_generate_field_access_events = 1;
  jc.can_generate_breakpoint_events = 1;
  return jc;
}

The above code states that can_generate_breakpoint_events capability and SetBreakpoint method are only allowed for agents that are started at OnLoad phase (oppose to dynamically attached agents, that are started at Live phase).
Question: Is there some reason for the described JVM behaviour ? Maybe some technical limitations? Or security concerns?

Sounds like a plausible technical limitation to me. The JVM just decides to operate in normal mode or debug mode at startup. So debug agents must be present already, to enable debugging.

@Holger Why not enable attach the debugger, do some work, and then detach ? This is a common practice, for example gdb debugger and others work exactly this way.

You wish for a JVM that is capable of supporting a debugger at any time. That’s the same as enabling debugging at startup. You can do that. Other people are willing to sacrifice debugging capabilities for more speed or less memory consumption. They have an option too. You don’t need to use that option if it doesn’t serve you.
